# load options of a select box dynamically based on value of another select box in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I m trying to create 2 select boxes in which options of 1st select box are fixed but the second ones change based on the selected value of first div.

eg:
1st Select:

```
<select>
    <option>Integers</option>
    <option>Alphabets</option>
</select>
```

Then if Integers is selected in 1st select then I want integers 1 to 10 as options in the 2nd select box. But if Alphabets is selected the a to z should come in options of the second select box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a lookup table object that holds both integers and Alphabets with each has a relevant key.
Then in one `select` you update the state with selected `key` and in the other `select` you render the options correspond to the selected `key`.

---

Here is a running example:

```js
const lookup = {
  "int": [
    { id: '1', text: '1' },
    { id: '2', text: '2' },
    { id: '3', text: '3' },
    { id: '4', text: '4' },
    { id: '5', text: '5' }
  ],
  "abc": [
    { id: 'a', text: 'a' },
    { id: 'b', text: 'b' },
    { id: 'c', text: 'c' },
    { id: 'd', text: 'd' },
    { id: 'e', text: 'e' }
  ]
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataValue: 'int'
    }
  }

  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ dataValue: value });
  }

  render() {
    const { dataValue } = this.state;
    const options = lookup[dataValue];
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onChange}>
          <option value="int">Integers</option>
          <option value="abc">Alphabets</option>
        </select>
        <hr />
        <select>
          {options.map(o => <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.text}</option>)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: but I have a complex structure and more than 20 options in the 1st select box. How can I create handle that

Comment: You didn't post your structure, the example i posted is due to the example you provided in the question. but actually it doesnt matter how complex your structure is, you can always normalize it and manipulate it inside `.map`

Comment: it is same what I am saying. This the requirement I just thought the lookup table will be very difficult to create. Just now I wrote a for loop to create lookup table dynamically and it works. Thanks for the idea. Really appreciate it.

Comment: yea I will, just let me verify it by coding it.

Comment: can you tell me how can i handle when initially dataValue is not set(Required). Because i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: you can either initialize it (like i did in the state) or don't run `.map` if it is not initialized: `dataValue && data[dataValue].map(o => {//...})`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="sel" onchange="ChangeList()"> 
  <option value="">select</option> 
  <option value="I">Integer</option> 
  <option value="A">Alphabet</option> 
</select> 

<select id="type"></select> 

<script>
var IntandAlph = {};
IntandAlph['I'] = ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
IntandAlph['A'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

function ChangeList() {
    var selList = document.getElementById("sel");
    var typeList = document.getElementById("type");
    var seltype = selList.options[selList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (typeList.options.length) {
        typeList.remove(0);
    }
    var Num = IntandAlph[seltype];
    if (Num) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Num.length; i++) {
            var sel = new Option(Num[i], i);
            typeList.options.add(sel);
        }
    }
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```