# ReactJS populate dropdown list based on first dropdown list selected value with ajax

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, dropdown

So I came across this post regarding this similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078627 the answer was correct but it is in javascript, how can I transform it into the way how react will handle this piece of code.

Below is the code in javascript

```
<select id="sel" onchange="ChangeList()"> 
  <option value="">select</option> 
  <option value="I">Integer</option> 
  <option value="A">Alphabet</option> 
</select> 

<select id="type"></select> 

<script>
var IntandAlph = {};
IntandAlph['I'] = ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
IntandAlph['A'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

function ChangeList() {
    var selList = document.getElementById("sel");
    var typeList = document.getElementById("type");
    var seltype = selList.options[selList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (typeList.options.length) {
        typeList.remove(0);
    }
    var Num = IntandAlph[seltype];
    if (Num) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Num.length; i++) {
            var sel = new Option(Num[i], i);
            typeList.options.add(sel);
        }
    }
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to React and web development as well, it would be great if you can enlighten me on this issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mendeleev-uhy2t) using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks to achieve the desired behavior, but there are plenty other ways to do it.

<strike>At start, I am declaring `options` as a constant object, with `keys` equal to the values of the the first select.</strike>

**EDIT 2:** After author's request, I've updated my sample fetching data from remote server instead of using a constant.

Then using `useState` I handle the user selection of the first select. When this value change, I look into my data state, for the appropriate array of data.

I strongly recommend you to take a look to [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for more details.

**EDIT:** I've added some comments on the code provided, explaining step by step the process.

Comment: Wonderful sir, this is exactly what I have been looking for, thank you for your work. A little addition to the request, is it possible to show how to fill the second dropdown list based on the first dropdown list selected with data filled from a json api instead of a local variable?

Comment: An example for the api would be something like this https://my-json-server.typicode.com/genjinim05/country/db

Comment: I've updated my example using `Fetch API` to fetch data from the URL provided. More about fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `value` of the first dropdown into the `state` upon selecting on the first dropdown.
And then you base the `options` of the second dropdown on the `state`.

Comment: I am sorry but it would be great if there is some demo code for me to understand, also I forgot to mention that the second dropdown list data should be filled with json from an api

Comment: Does that api has something like a foreign key from the first dropdown?