# Nodejs populate dropdown list based on first dropdown list selected value with ajax

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, express, handlebars.js

I have made a question regarding this similar topic recently, but it was in ReactJS and now I need to do it in NodeJS.

This is the link for the one in ReactJS,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59693724/12693684

I am trying to populate the second dropdown list based on the first dropdown list selected value, the second dropdown list should be filled with an JSON API. I am currently using Express and Handlebars.

Is there a way to do it in NodeJS or should I just call the static page and uses jQuery to accomplish the task?

This is what have I done so far

country.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Country-State</title>
    <!--Load bootstrap.css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Country-State</h2>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                <label>Choose your country</label>
                <br/><br/>
                <select id="sel">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                </select>
                  <select id="type" name="select">
                      <option value=""></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Load bootstrap.js file-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
```

index.js

```
app.get('/countrystate', (req,res) => {
    const url="http://localhost:4000/db";
    const fetchData = async url => {
        try 
        {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const result = await response.json();
            console.log(result)
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    fetchData(url);
    res.render('country');
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understood your question fully, but here is what you can do to pass those data in your static page country.hbs

To populate use: res.render('country', fetchData)
then you can recieve it in your hbs file and map it in that dropdown