# load options of a select box dynamically based on value of another select box but dependent select is not defaulting to first option

Tags: reactjs

I have two select boxes where the second is dynamic and it's contents depend on which selection is made in the first select box.
I am able to get the second select to dynamically change based on the selection of box one however if I select an option in dynamic box two then change the selection of box one, when the contents of box two changes the default selected item in box two is not the first option in that select box.
How can I get it to default back to the first value in box two every time the contents changes?

Please see below code snippet.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const areas = [
  {
    code: "01",
    field: "Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences",
    subFields: [
      { code: "01.00", field: "Agriculture, General" },
      { code: "01.01", field: "Agricultural Business And Management" },
      { code: "01.02", field: "Agricultural Mechanization" },
      { code: "01.03", field: "Agricultural Production Operations" },
      {
        code: "01.04",
        field: "Agricultural And Food Products Processing"
      },
      {
        code: "01.05",
        field: "Agricultural And Domestic Animal Services"
      },
      {
        code: "01.06",
        field: "Applied Horticulture And Horticultural Business Services"
      },
      { code: "01.07", field: "International Agriculture" },
      { code: "01.08", field: "Agricultural Public Services" },
      { code: "01.09", field: "Animal Sciences" },
      { code: "01.10", field: "Food Science And Technology" },
      { code: "01.11", field: "Plant Sciences" },
      { code: "01.12", field: "Soil Sciences" },
      {
        code: "01.99",
        field:
          "Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences, Other"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    code: "03",
    field: "Natural Resources And Conservation",
    subFields: [
      {
        code: "03.01",
        field: "Natural Resources Conservation And Research"
      },
      { code: "03.02", field: "Natural Resources Management And Policy" },
      {
        code: "03.03",
        field: "Fishing And Fisheries Sciences And Management"
      },
      { code: "03.05", field: "Forestry" },
      {
        code: "03.06",
        field: "Wildlife And Wildlands Science And Management"
      },
      {
        code: "03.99",
        field: "Natural Resources And Conservation, Other"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    code: "04",
    field: "Architecture And Related Services",
    subFields: [
      { code: "04.02", field: "Architecture" },
      {
        code: "04.03",
        field: "City/Urban, Community And Regional Planning"
      },
      { code: "04.04", field: "Environmental Design" },
      { code: "04.05", field: "Interior Architecture" },
      { code: "04.06", field: "Landscape Architecture" },
      { code: "04.08", field: "Architectural History And Criticism" },
      { code: "04.09", field: "Architectural Sciences And Technology" },
      { code: "04.10", field: "Real Estate Development" },
      {
        code: "04.99",
        field: "Architecture And Related Services, Other"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fieldIndex: 0
  });

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    // console.log(value);
    setState({ fieldIndex: value });
  };

  const { fieldIndex } = state;
  const options = areas[fieldIndex].subFields;

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        {areas.map((o, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={i}>
            {o.field}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <hr />
      <select>
        {options.map((o, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={i}>
            {o.field}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-williams-3w0s5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Other resources:
This is building on this example, but his defaults to the first option in the dynamic select box and mine is not.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48076956/2199540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your second `select` to restore to its first `option` whenever the first `select` changes.
You should use something more than just the `index` for the key prop, for instance you can use

`key={o.code + i}`

for both first select options and second ones.
This is because re-rendering the second select, react does not realise the changes since most of the keys remain unchanged (0, 1, 2, ...)

See if [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shirley-dn1k2?file=/src/App.js) solves it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation really helped me understand why it is acting this way!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't guarantee different keys, you could use state to save the sub field value and reset it whenever you change the first `select`

```
const App = () => {
  const [fieldIndex, setFieldIndex] = useState(0);
  const [subFieldIndex, setSubFieldIndex] = useState(0);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    // console.log(value);
    setFieldIndex(value);
    setSubFieldIndex(0);
  };

  const onChangeSub = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setSubFieldIndex(value);
  };

  const options = areas[fieldIndex].subFields;

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        {areas.map((o, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={i}>
            {o.field}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <hr />
      <select value={subFieldIndex} onChange={onChangeSub}>
        {options.map((o, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={i}>
            {o.field}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Here is a working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-banach-hjs33?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that is was an issue! Also this is a good option for a work around.